# Can netty send more than one response per client request

Tags: java, client-server, netty, tcp

I have a `TCP/IP socket server` which send `multiple response` to `client` based on client's requirement ( like send update whenever DB has an update). `client` sends `xml` and `server` too respond `xml`.

I stumbled on `Netty` yesterday. I want to know whether `Netty` can support my multiple response `server` application?

Answer (score 1):

Sure as long as the protocol which is used can handle this kind of message flow.

Comment: I use simple socket connection which means server listen to clients and validate the user login send back login resp with "OK". Then my app start back end thread to read DB updates and send to client. ( in this case server side work as a client) Hope you understood what is my requirement.

Comment: Appreciate if you can advice